# Half-delayed evaluation

Tags: evaluation

In a certain wider context, I need to make some delayed definitions, such as `x := a + b + c`, but within these definitions I want `a` and `b` to be evaluated to their current values, not their later values. Here's a bit of code that does the trick:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 5;
With[{a = a, b = b}, x := a + b + c; y := b + c];
a = 10; b = 20; c = 50;
```

If `x` is printed at the end, it comes out to be `53` and if its definition is inspected with `?x`, it comes out to be `x := 1 + 2 + c`. Likewise at the end `y` is `y := 2 + c`.

This is precisely the behaviour I want, but within my wider context, I care about elegance and this is inelegant. So I'd like to be able to define a command (really, a "macro") `WithCurrent`, so that `WithCurrent[{a, b}, delayeddefs]` would be equivalent to `With[{a = a, b = b}, delayeddefs]`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to define such a macro:

```
SetAttributes[withCurrent, HoldAll]
withCurrent[{v:(_Symbol...)}, body_] :=
  Replace[Hold[v], s_ :> (s = s), {1}] /. _[a___] :> With[{a}, body]
```

`withCurrent` is given the `HoldAll` attribute to delay the evaluation of the arguments until after we have had a chance to process them.  It wraps the supplied sequence of symbols in `Hold` and then uses `Replace` to convert each symbol into a "self-assignment".  The resulting held assignments are then transformed into the desired `With` statement by means of a replacement rule.

Example:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 5;
withCurrent[{a, b}, x := a + b + c; y := b + c];
a = 10; b = 20; c = 50;

?x
(* x := 1 + 2 + c *)

?y
(* y := 2 + c *)

x
(* 53 *)

y
(* 52 *)
```

If desired, we can add a definition to `withCurrent` that causes it to fail noisily if it is called with invalid arguments:

```
w:withCurrent[___] := (Message[withCurrent::malformed, Short@HoldForm[w]]; Abort[])
withCurrent::malformed = "Malformed use of withCurrent: ``";
```

Example:

```
withCurrent[{a, b, c = 3}, a + b]
(*
withCurrent::malformed: Malformed use of withCurrent: withCurrent[{a,b,c=3},a+b]
$Aborted
*)
```

This is usually a good defensive-programming measure when defining macros.  Otherwise, malformed usage in larger programs might cause strange results that are not detected until long after the macro has been called.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to use the injection pattern.

```
SetAttributes[WithCurrent, HoldAll]
WithCurrent[list_, delayeddefs___] := 
With[{ls = 
      Replace[Map[Hold, Replace[Hold@list, Hold[{x___}] :> Hold[x]], 
        1], Hold[x_] :> (x = x), -1]}, 
    Hold[With[ls, delayeddefs]] /. Hold[x___Set] :> {x}] // ReleaseHold
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
WithCurrent[{a, b}, x := a + b + c]
?x
(* x:=1+2+c *)
```

One minor issue I see is that last `ReplaceAll` may be too strong - you don't normally see `Hold[___Set]` patterns in regular expressions but if they appear anywhere else they'll get replaced. Also, any `Hold` values in `delayeddefs` will get released. This shouldn't be a problem if `delayeddefs` consists of delayed definitions as the name suggests.